# C++ Multiple Classes Cause Architecture Error

Tags: c++, class, importerror

I am working on a project that requires me to use a variety of classes.
For some reason, whenever I try compiling, I get an error that says:
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`

I originally was working on a class we can call `User` that had a declaration like this in `user.h`:

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
...other include statements

class User
{
    public:
    User();
    public and private members and functions
};

#endif
```

Definitions of the methods was housed in a separate file in the same directory, `user.cpp`.

Whenever I would try to compile, I would get an error saying there were undefined symbols for the constructor and destructor. I had both of these defined in the `.cpp` file, but I couldn't get the error to go away.

I include the User class in main with the following:

```
#include "user.h"
```

I managed to fix this by pasting all code from the `user.cpp` file into `user.h`, but now I am having issues with other classes whose code I am not allowed to modify.

Right now, I have a class called GMLReader in `gmlreader.h` with a method I am calling statically. However, even though I am importing it for my main, I am getting the following error code whenever I try to call it:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "GMLReader::read(char const*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)", referenced from:
      _main in cchnzOEh.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using the following to compile with `sn.cpp` housing my main:

```
g++ -g -Wall -o sn sn.cpp
```

Is there any reason an error like this would have occurred and how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: I've gotten this error a lot before, make sure you are passing the right types of variables to the function

Comment: Is your target architecture indeed 64-bit?  It could be that some files are compiling for 32-bit and others for 64-bit.

Comment: Also, show us the `#include` statements and how you are compiling the code.

Comment: you are not showing relative code, please show the real code

Comment: i've seen this issue before, and i think it's unrelated to the architecture.  it's pretty much like an unresolved external.  seems GMLReader::read can't be found.

Comment: I'm thinking if I can solve it for User, I solve it for GMLReader. It's more a problem across all code I'm using

Comment: When you compile, are you passing all of the CPP files as arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile and link user.cpp as well:

```
g++ -g -Wall -c user.cpp -o user.o
g++ -g -Wall -o sn sn.cpp user.o
```

Comment: Thank you. Was used to having a Makefile and not having to supply all these arguments, but it all works now